# $6p|\:a+b+c\ $ then $:6p|\:a^p+b^p+c^p$

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory

$6p|\:a+b+c\ $  then $:6p|\:a^p+b^p+c^p$

i solved a similar problem using Fermat's little theorem and my textbook hinted on using the same one here, but not sure how.

Comment: Hint: this is easy to see that $2\mid a^p+b^p+c^p$ and $3\mid a^p+b^p+c^p$ (you can, but don't have to, use Fermat's little theorem). Divisibility by $p$ is an extremely direct application of this theorem.

Comment: This doesn't work for $p=2,p=3$ though

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming $p$ is an odd prime greater than $3$, you have, directly by FlT, that $a^p+b^p+c^p \equiv a+b+c \equiv 0 (\bmod{p}).$  Now you just have to show that $6\mid a^p+b^p+c^p$.  Since $2\mid a+b+c$, then either $0$ or $2$ of $a, b, c$ are odd.  Therefore either $0$ or $2$ of $a^p, b^p, c^p$ are odd, so $2 \mid a^p+b^p+c^p.$  Likewise, every integer is congruent to $-1, 0$ or $1$ modulo $3$, so raising it to an odd power doesn't change the congruence class.  So if $3\mid a+b+c$ it also divides $a^p+b^p+c^p$.